# REST Client Patch Step on Pentaho

Tags: rest, pentaho

i'm working on a Pentaho procedure and i'm stuck in a REST client step where it performs a patch call to update a certain field in a JSON file.The API is from IT Portal ([IT Portal](https://www.itportal.com/v4/))
I tried to do this operation directly on API web page and with Postman and everything works fine but in Pentaho we obtain an invalid JSON as response (error 400).

Below an image of how the step looks like, with the parameters:

[REST Client step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aunhs.png)
**url_licences_used** contains the request URL from the API
**patch_licences_used** contains the body, in this case {"value:"5}

The response i obtain is always the same: [Error 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkci7.png)

I wonder if anybody has ever witnessed this kind of problem, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you